# How conversion from T to Task<T> works? Fixing task.Result block to UI thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm reading the Jon Skeet's book "C# in Depth". On **15.2.2** we have the following example:

```
static async Task<int> GetPageLengthAsync(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Task<string> fetchTextTask = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        int length = (await fetchTextTask).Length;
        return length; // How this is converted to Task<int> ?
    }
}
static void PrintPageLength()
{
    Task<int> lengthTask =
    GetPageLengthAsync("http://csharpindepth.com");
    Console.WriteLine(lengthTask.Result); // This blocks the UI thread!!
}
```

I have two problems here:

1. How it happens that the `return length` on the first method works when the return type is `Task<int>`?
2. I think that the `Console.WriteLine(lengthTask.Result);` blocks the UI thread. The only way I made it working was by changing it to: `lengthTask.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);`
   Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that the Console.WriteLine(lengthTask.Result); blocks the UI thread. The only way I made it working was by changing it to: lengthTask.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously); Is this correct?

Yes this is correct. `Console.WriteLine(lengthTask.Result)` will block your UI thread but it will work fine in a console app as console apps use a Thread Pool sycnrhonization context which ash multiple threads.

The solution you adopted with `ContinueWith` will work, this is something you can also do with async-await, which essentially automatically schedules the rest of the method as a continuation:

```
static async Task PrintPageLength()
{
    Task<int> lengthTask =
    GetPageLengthAsync("http://csharpindepth.com");
    Console.WriteLine(await lengthTask.ConfigureAwait(false));
}
```

The `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used to avoid context swtiching after the asynchronous work is done, similar to the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` you use with `ContinueWith`.

> How it happens that the return length on the first method works when the return type is Task?

Async-await code is not what you see is what you get. It compiles to a state machine. If you disassemble your code it looks more like this:

```
 [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<GetPageLengthAsync>d__0)), DebuggerStepThrough]
 private static Task<int> GetPageLengthAsync(string url)
 {
     <GetPageLengthAsync>d__0 d__;
      d__.url = url;
      d__.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();        
      d__.<>1__state = -1;
      d__.<>t__builder.Start<<GetPageLengthAsync>d__0>(ref d__);
      return d__.<>t__builder.Task;
  }
```

The state machine looks like this:

```
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private struct <GetPageLengthAsync>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
    {
        public int <>1__state;
        public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder;
        private object <>t__stack;
        private TaskAwaiter<string> <>u__$awaiter4;
        public HttpClient <client>5__1;
        public Task<string> <fetchTextTask>5__2;
        public int <length>5__3;
        public string url;

        private void MoveNext()
        {
            int num;
            try
            {
                bool flag = true;
                switch (this.<>1__state)
                {
                    case -3:
                        goto Label_0113;

                    case 0:
                        break;

                    default:
                        this.<client>5__1 = new HttpClient();
                        break;
                }
                try
                {
                    TaskAwaiter<string> awaiter;
                    if (this.<>1__state != 0)
                    {
                        this.<fetchTextTask>5__2 = this.<client>5__1.GetStringAsync(this.url);
                        awaiter = this.<fetchTextTask>5__2.GetAwaiter();
                        if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            this.<>1__state = 0;
                            this.<>u__$awaiter4 = awaiter;
                            this.<>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter<string>, Form1.<GetPageLengthAsync>d__0>(ref awaiter, ref this);
                            flag = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        awaiter = this.<>u__$awaiter4;
                        this.<>u__$awaiter4 = new TaskAwaiter<string>();
                        this.<>1__state = -1;
                    }
                    string result = awaiter.GetResult();
                    awaiter = new TaskAwaiter<string>();
                    int length = result.Length;
                    this.<length>5__3 = length;
                    num = this.<length>5__3;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (flag && (this.<client>5__1 != null))
                    {
                        this.<client>5__1.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.<>1__state = -2;
                this.<>t__builder.SetException(exception);
                return;
            }
        Label_0113:
            this.<>1__state = -2;
            this.<>t__builder.SetResult(num);
        }

        [DebuggerHidden]
        private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine param0)
        {
            this.<>t__builder.SetStateMachine(param0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. However, I tested `.ConfigureAwait(false); + await lengthTask` on WinForms and it crashed. It worked well with `ConfigureAwait(true)`

Comment: Sorry that should have been `Console.WriteLine(await lengthTask.ConfigureAwait(false));`, otherwise you get a compiler error. I tested that this morning and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1/ If you read further (15.3.5):

> You can see that the type of length is int, but the return type of the
>   method is Task. The generated code takes care of the wrapping for
>   you, so that the caller gets a Task, which will eventually have
>   the value returned from the method when it completes.

2/ You're right, the call to `Result` is a blocking call. This has no unconvenient consequence in a Console app, but it would in a GUI. You would typically use `await` on the UI thread to prevent that easily:

```
myTextBlock.Text = await GetPageLengthAsync("http://csharpindepth.com");
```

This (in an async method of course) will also prevent possible deadlock (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx or http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: I new that I have to read further :) but instead, I spend several hours in experiments. Finally decided that this is a part of TPL magic.

Comment: Be sure to check the links, I don't remember if Jon talks about that in his book. Always use `async/await` when possible, it's easier to read AND prevents some synchronization problems.

Answer (score 1):

> How it happens that the `return length` on the first method works when the return type is `Task<int>`?

As I describe in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), the `async` keyword does two things: it enables the `await` keyword, and it introduces a state machine that changes how the results are handled. The details of the state machine are not that important; what you need to know is that the state machine is responsible for constructing and controlling the `Task<int>` that is returned.

When the `async` method reaches its first `await` and asynchronously waits for that operation, it returns an incomplete `Task<int>`. Later, when the `async` method reaches a `return` statement, it completes the `Task<int>` with that result value.

> I think that the `Console.WriteLine(lengthTask.Result);` blocks the UI thread. The only way I made it working was by changing it to: `lengthTask.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);` Is this correct?

No.

While that code would work in this situation, it would be far better to use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```
static async Task PrintPageLengthAsync()
{
  Task<int> lengthTask = GetPageLengthAsync("http://csharpindepth.com");
  Console.WriteLine(await lengthTask);
}
```

`ContinueWith` has a number of [unsafe default options](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) that I describe in detail on my blog. It is far easier to write correct code with `await` than `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Thank you. I started reading your concurrency series. I find it very useful. Your book looks also interesting and exactly in the matter I'm learning now.